# Problem with a Delphi dbxpress application after upgrading Windows Server 2008 to Windows server 2012

Tags: delphi, interbase, dbexpress

I want to upgrade a Windows server 2008 to windows Server 2012, and, if possible, 2016 and 2019.
This server runs a Delphi XE2 Interbase XE3 dbexpress application. 
After upgrading the server to windows server 2012, compilation of the app is OK, but it breaks during connection to the Database:
DBX error: Driver could not be properly initialized
Client library May be missing, of the wrong version,
May be missing from the driver or the system path

How to fix that ? Update the driver (dbxint.dll ?) ? upgrade to Delphi 10 ?

Thanks

Comment: You not only need the dbxpress driver for interbase (dbxint.dll) but also de Interbase client library (gds32.dll or ibclient64.dll).

Comment: How do I get updated versions of dbxint.dll and gds32.dll ?

Comment: Here you have the installation guide of the client (it's not enough to copy the gds32 dll, you also need the interbase.msg and msvcrt.dll, and some configuration). https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27574#Minimal%20Client%20Installation

Comment: I would use the dbxint.dll that comes with the latest update of your Delphi XE2, and the gds32.dll, interbase.msg and msvcrt.dll that come on the installer of the latest update of your Interbase version.

Comment: These 3 files are those already present with WindowsServer 2008 and seem OK. What is strange is that IBconsole works and can connect to the database. But this upgrade to Windows server 2012 caused problems with Delphi dbexpress components.

Comment: Any other idea ?

Comment: Check that DBConnections.Ini and DBXDrivers.Ini are on the new server, that your app can find them and that they contain correct paths, if there are any explicit ones. If those are all ok, check that your server app is on the system path.

Answer (score 0):

I copied a newer version (12.0.354) of gds32.dll into windows32\system32 and it WORKS now !!!  I get this version from a Delphi 10 installation.